# How can pass the current datetime to string in python?

Tags: python, string, datetime

I'm trying to pass the current date and time of activities to string value so that whenever I saved my picture or anything during the program it can be saved by its own certain name + **current time** together but I faced error probably due to `:` ! 
Following format would fulfill my expectation :

```
2019-05-22 21-33-34 instead of 2019-05-22 21:33:34.433134
```

```py
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dtime = dt.time()
now=dt.datetime.now()
now.isoformat()
print(now)

...

plt.savefig(f'{now}.png')

...

test_RNN.to_csv(f'test_RNN_history{now}.csv', sep=',', header=None, index=None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the timestamp to a string and then can use the [replace()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) method to change the `:` to `-`

```
str(now).replace(":","-")
```