# Reading and parsing a CSV file in Python with Regex first column

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file (calendar), 5 columns that I want to read and parse with the following conditions using a script:

- Deleting headers (done)
- Change the format of the first column from 01/01/2019 to 20190101 in the First column

The first part of the script is done to skip headers. The second part I think a regex is required but I just don't know how to first remove the / and then move the 0101 from before 2019 to after 2019 so that the result is 20190101

If someone could help that would be great!

```
def parse_calendar(infile, outfile):
    with open(outfile, 'w', newline='') as output:
        with open(infile, newline='') as input:
            reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
            writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            for row in reader:   # process each row
                writer.writerow(row)
```

I expect the output to be like the following compared to the initial file:

01/01/2019  New Year's Day  N   C   US

20190101    New Year's Day  N   C   US

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can pass the current datetime to string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263851/how-can-pass-the-current-datetime-to-string-in-python) You can convert the timestamp to a string and then can use the [replace()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) method to change the `/` : to `` or backspace

Comment: It’s not a duplicate. The column is part of a csv file and is not a timestamp type. Plus also if you remove the ‘/‘ , I still need something that moves the first 4 characters after the last one, meaning 01012019 has to become 20190101. And would be best if it’s code added to the script I already have. This action is performed on the first column in the file. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see eye to eye with you. Nevertheless you could use [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and  modify it from `("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")` to any form you want to.

Comment: @V.Montréal seems like you already have a way to do most of what you want. I'd say your question boils down to just "how to change the format of a date string in python?"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the responses.

So with this code I get the following output:

```
import csv

def parse_calendar(infile, outfile):
    with open(outfile, 'w', newline='') as output:
        with open(infile, newline='') as input:
            reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
            writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            for row in reader: # process each row
                replaced = row[0].replace('/','')  
                row[0] = replaced
                writer.writerow(row)
```

01012018,New Year's Day,N,C,US

01012018,New Year's Day,N,C,CA

01152018,Martin L. King Day,N,C,US

What code do I need to add to the script get the formatting different now from 01012018 to 20180101 given the type is a String? For each line then off course.

Appreciate it alot thanks